# C - Extra new line input while using scanf()

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, scanf

I have the below 'C' code for a Console Win32 application using Visual Studio. It checks for arguments and directly calls a function or gets inputs using `scanf()` and then calls the function. The program works perfectly if I give command line arguments, but when I give inputs using `scanf()`, it probably adds an extra new line character which I want to avoid.

I know it does this because when I give arguments, after showing 'Press ENTER to quit...', it waits for the ENTER input, but doesn't do so when using `scanf()`. This problem occurs if I use `scanf_s()` too.

Appreciate your help on this.

Regards,

Shahid

```
    unsigned long int ipv;
    unsigned int yrs;
    float acr, acl, asp, irr, psp;

        if(argc<=1) {
            //get inputs
            printf("Initial value of portfolio: "); scanf("%lu", &ipv);
            printf("Average cash rate: "); scanf("%f", &acr);
            printf("Average cost of living: "); scanf("%f", &acl);
            printf("Average return for share portfolio: "); scanf("%f", &asp);
            printf("Initial removal for living expenses: "); scanf("%f", &irr);
            printf("Percentage of shares in initial portfolio: "); scanf("%f", &psp);
            printf("Years for the analysis: "); scanf("%u", &yrs);

            //simulate the investment with given inputs
            simulate(ipv, acr, acl, asp, irr, psp, yrs);
        } else {
            if (argc == 8) {
                //invsim 1000000 0.05 0.036 0.12 0.08 0.5 20

                //simulate the investment with given inputs
                simulate(atol(argv[1]), (float)atof(argv[2]), (float)atof(argv[3]), (float)atof(argv[4]), (float)atof(argv[5]), (float)atof(argv[6]), atoi(argv[7]));
            } else {
                printf("Please enter arguments as...\ninvsim.exe ipv acr acl asp irr psp yrs");
            }
        }

printf("\n\nPress ENTER to quit...");
getchar();
```

Comment: I like both Sourav's and VolAnd's simple solution. The former was first and the latter's was slightly more complete. What is the right logic in choosing an answer and closing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve your "pause" feature use the following update:

```
 printf("\n\nPress ENTER to quit...");
 while( getchar() != '\n' ); // clear the input buffer after reading numbers with scanf
 getchar();  // wait for new input
```

**EDIT:**

Taking into account the `if-else` of your program, move suggested `while` loop above:

```
 printf("Years for the analysis: "); 
 scanf("%u", &yrs);
 while( getchar() != '\n' ); // clear the input buffer
```

Comment: For the first approach, you've to press ENTER twice while supplying values via command line, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> I know it does this because when I give arguments, after showing 'Press ENTER to quit...', it waits for the ENTER input, but doesn't do so when using scanf().

That is the right behaviour, isn't it? When you supply arguments via command line, you're not pressing any <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. So, there is no `\n` in the input buffer. So, `getchar()` will wait for the input from `stdin`.

However, when you intake values using `scanf()`, you press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key after the inputs. For numerical values, the numeric value is scanned but the `\n` (produced by hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)is remained in the input buffer to be read by next `getchar()`. So, your code doesn't *wait*.

To resolve: add one `getchar();` at the end of the the `scanf()` part of code, i.e, at the end of `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, it's one of the more frustrating parts of C. I can't remember exactly what I did, but I remember that I ended up writing a small library to handle each type of input, ie, string, number, etc.

IIRC, I just used getline() and parsed the string into the type that I needed using atoi() and the other conversion functions found in ctype.h; I checked the length of the string and if it was 1(?) the only way that happens is if there was a new line already in the buffer, so I just called getline() again.

In this way, I could write the input validation ONCE, and use it a million times. So my code ended up looking like:

```
do {
      get_int("Enter an integer:", &myInt);//returns -123456789 for invalid input, or such
 } while ( myInt <= 0 )//assuming you only wanted positive input
```

This also has the non-trivial benefit of not seeing your program crash when you entered a string and scanf() is expecting an integer.